# MySQL, Filter records in a table based on values in two other separate tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to filter financial records on a MySQL table A based on mapping constraints stored on two separate tables B and C where:
i. Table 1 has Budget and Expenditure amounts by Project Donors, Work Breakdown Structure IDs
, and Year

```
wbs year    donor   budget  exp
1   2019    a         10    10
2   2019    b         11    11
3   2020    c         12    12
4   2020    d         13    13
```

ii. Table 2 has Project IDs and their constituent Work Breakdown Structure IDs

```
project wbs
001     1
002     2
003     3
001     4
002     5
003     6
```

iii. Table 3 has Project IDs and corresponding Donors.

```
project donor
001     a
002     b
003     c
001     d
002     a
003     b
```

I would like to view the total budgets and expenditures for all projects listed.
I have written the following query:

```
SELECT
    `t2`.`project` AS `project`,
    `t2`.`wbs` AS `wbs`,
    `t1`.`year` AS `year`,
    `t1`.`grant` AS `grant`,
    `t1`.`funded_program_key` AS `funded_program_key`,
    `t1`.`budget` AS `budget`,
    `t1`.`exp` AS `exp`
FROM
    `wbs_table` `t2` 
    
    LEFT JOIN `expenditure_table` `t1` ON  `t2`.`wbs` = `t1`.`wbs`
    
    LEFT JOIN `donor_table` `t3` ON  `t1`.`donor` = `t3`.`donor`
    
WHERE `t3`.`project` = `t2`.`project` 

AND `t3`.`project` IS NOT NULL
```

However, figures appear to be missing when it is run and I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

This is what my desired table result should look like:

```
project   wbs   year  donor  budget  exp
001       1     2019    a    10      10
002       2     2019    b    11      11
003       3     2020    c    12      12
```

Comment: The aliases for `wbs_table` and `expenditure_table` do they match with the query you tried?

Comment: @SamuelMwamburi can you post a sample of what your desired result set should look like?

Comment: Show desired output for shown data.

Comment: Be advised that `LEFT JOIN t3 ... WHERE t3.project = ...` is the same as `INNER JOIN t3...`

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak , Please find desired output on edited post.

Comment: @Akina , , Please find desired output on the edited post.

Comment: *my desired table result should look like* Why the row with `wbs=4` is not listed in the output?

Comment: @Akina i have just shown the first three rows of the sample output to illustrate the idea of what I am trying to achieve which is filtering the expenditure table to show projects that exist on both the donor and wbs tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of process is not described at all.

But, looking on column names and values I propose the next query:

```sql
SELECT project, wbs, e.year, donor, e.budget, e.exp
FROM expenditure_table e
JOIN wbs_table w USING (wbs)
JOIN donor_table в USING (project, donor);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ed23d0bcee9c4dc3f12eea383c4aa79

Comment: this is really helpful as I was not aware of the possibility of joining a table using two fields simultaneously in this case donor table on both project id and donor.